# Highcharts xAxis labels alignment

Tags: highcharts, label

I try to properly align the xAxis.labels. See screenshot. But I can't properly align them to the left? They pop out the screen on the left side?

[image]

If I inspect the element, I see something is wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a live example ? (JSFiddle)

Comment: No, not in JSFiddle. How do I get [this example](https://test.staatvenz.nl/kerncijfers/betaald-werk) in JSFiddle?

Comment: Just copy paste the code in a Fiddle. I think you can use a Left Margin to see full labels: see design & styles http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style

Comment: @Kabulan0lak but if I look at the [xAxis.labels documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels) I don't see any Left Margin options for the labels?

Comment: You should put a margin to your whole chart, not just labels.

Comment: In this case you can use spacingLeft parameter. If you will still have problems with your cart please post live example of your issue, like jsFiddle: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacingLeft